# How do I create a pause in the execution of the code

Tags: php

I am wanting to create a list that reveals itself slowly on the screen, but it seems that all routines are completed before they present themselves.

For example:

```
for ($x = 0; $x <= 25; $x++)
{
 echo "The number is: $x <br>";
 sleep(1);
}
```

In my mind this should display "The number is 1",  wait 1 second then display "The number is 2".  In reality is waits 25 seconds and shows all the numbers, except there seems to be an error there too as it only actually displays the first 10 !!!

EDIT: I also tried "usleep" which had the same effect

I'm not concerned with the error, but how do I add some waiting please?

EDIT: Following on, I am still getting the same issue with this code.

```
 for ($x = 1; $x < 5; $x++)
 {
  $st=$_SESSION['st']=$x;
  echo '<iframe class="findlist" name="iframefindlist" id="findlist" src="findmelist.php"></iframe>';
  ob_flush();
  flush();
  usleep(3000000);
 }
```

And then the "findmelist.php" is

```
<body>
<?php
$st=$_SESSION['st'];
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "acc", "pw", "db");

?>
<div class="findlist1">
</div>

<div class="findlist2">
 <?php

 $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE number='$st'");
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {
  $fname=$row['fname'];
  $lname=$row['lname'];
 }
 echo $fname.' '.$lname;
 ?>
</div>

<div class="findlist3">
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: I think you're looking for JavaScript. PHP only presents the page after all operations have completed.

Comment: That's not true @Someone_who_likes_SE. PHP supports that pretty well ;)

Answer (score 3):

You need to flush the output_buffer first, otherwise the answer is only sent when the execution has finished.

```
ob_flush();
flush();
```

So for your code, that means:

```
for ($x = 0; $x <= 25; $x++)
{
 echo "The number is: $x <br>";
 ob_flush();
 flush();
 sleep(1);
}
```

For more info, see the following [reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php).

Comment: more info: https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php

Comment: Thanks, will add it to the answer @Luuk!

Comment: @maio290 I implemented the suggestion on the code i first presented and it worked OK, but now I have added it to my actual site, the issue has reared its ugly head again